# Splitting String at Dash and Returning Everything After First Dash

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract the entire string after the first dash, however it is turning the values into a list instead of just the string. For instance abc-123-test turns into ['123','test']. How could I instead have it return 123-test. I've tried the bottom two lines below. I understand string splitting and returning multiple values as a list is as designed, however how I could I have it just return everything after the first dash. Thanks

```
t = {'test_string':['abc-123-test']}
test = pd.DataFrame(data=t)
test['id'] = test['test_string'].str.split('-').str[0]
test['id_string'] = test['test_string'].str.split('-').str[1:].astype(str)
test['id_string'] = str(test['test_string'].str.split('-').str[1:].astype(str))
```

Comment: You could also just use `'-'.join(test['test_string'].str.split('-').str[1:])` to get it in the format you want

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and simply pick/[`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the portion after the first dash (`-`) :

```
test["id_string"] = test["test_string"].str.extract("-(.+)", expand=False)
```

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/FJmOfx/2)]

​
Output :

```
print(test)

    test_string id_string
0  abc-123-test  123-test
```

Comment: You don't need the lookbehind though. A simple `-(.+)` is enough ;)

Comment: Hi mozway, thank you. I just updated the code and the demo as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```py
t = {'test_string':['abc-123-test']}
t = t['test_string'][0]
index = t.find('-') + 1
st = t[index:]
print(st)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the amount of times to split the value, as a second argument of *[str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)*.

```py
'abc-123-test'.split('-', 1)
```

Output

```
['abc', '123-test']
```

So, you'd use the following.

```py
string = 'abc-123-test'.split('-', 1)[1]
```

Additionally, you could just locate the index and return a substring.

```py
string = 'abc-123-test'
string = string[string.index('-') + 1:]
```

Output

```
123-test
```